How to remove a mirror from OSGeo4W installer
When I run the OSGeo4W installer to upgrade my QGIS installation, there is a page on the dialog where you choose the mirrors you want to use. I must have first installed QGIS a while ago, because one of the items on the list is still using http:// protocol.
The installer gives me a warning about this, and I have to click Yes it's ok to ignore this mirror during the install. I'd like to remove the mirror from the list so I don't get the warning, but there doesn't seem to be a way to remove items from the list. There is a big Add button to add new mirrors, and I've searched the registry in case the list was stored there somewhere.
Anyone know how to remove a mirror from the list?
